# how to set href value at runtime through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

i have created a html page which contain two iframe .

first iframe refer another html which contain a list of members
this list is not fixed and every member name there is a separate html page. which is shown by second iframe.

i have written some javascript code to get the value of that list but i am unable to update the src link of second iframe.

```
document.getElementById("frame2").setAttribute("src", name);
```

i have used this code to set the value but i didn't work. i have written this code in javascript file in setFileName(name) function.this is user define function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got my answer

> top.parent.frame2.location = name;

like this we can change the src of another frame.

thanks all of you..

Answer (score 1):

might want to give this a try:

```
window.frames["frame2"].src = name
```

Information from: [Changing Iframe source using Javascript](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/2263.htm)

Comment: thanks 4 you reply but my doubt is diffrent i have one index.html file and it contain two iframe 1st iframe display test.html file which contain the list of member when i click on any member name it call a javascript method  in this method i want to change the src value of 2nd iframe in index.html file

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this query once and following article helped me. Hopefully it will be useful to resolve your issue.

http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/

Comment: thanks 4 you reply but my doubt is diffrent i have one index.html file and it contain two iframe 1st iframe display test.html file which contain the list of member when i click on any member name it call a javascript method  in this method i want to change the src value of 2nd iframe in index.html file